# Can we use "to" before home, if we are using determiners (her, my, your etc.) before home?

Tags: american-english, british-english, determiners, indirect-objects

**I know these sentences are correct:**

> I am going home.
>
> I am coming home.
>
> I went home.

**Please let me know, are these sentences also correct or not:**

> I am going to her home.
>
> I am coming to your home.
>
> I went to his home/house.

**Or these are correct:**

> I went her home.
>
> I am going her home.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/why-is-to-not-used-before-home

Comment: Bizarrely, I find myself interpreting OP's last pair as being more likely to be a non-native speaker's faulty rendering of something like *I **saw** her home*, or *I **walked** her home* (I went with her as an escort, to make sure she got home safely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting question: *home* is quirky.

- Bare *home*—no preposition, no determiner—always means the home of the person in question: the person who is *going home* or *staying home* or *leaving home*.

  > I'm going home. ... *means* my *home*
  >   We're staying home. ... *means* our *home*
  >   She's leaving home. *means* her *home*
- With the prepositions *at* and *from*, the determiner may be omitted if the home in question is that of the person in question.

  > I'm at home right now. ... *I'm at my home.*
  >   We came straight from home. ... *We came from our home.*
- But if a determiner is used—any determiner, even one which defines the home in question as being that of the person in question—the preposition is also required.

  > He's going to Lynne's home.   *He's going Lynne's home.
  >   I'm going to my home now.   *I'm going my home.
- If two people are involved, it gets tricky; you may need a determiner or other context to disambiguate.

  > I saw her home. ... *will almost always mean* her *home*
  >   I brought her home. ... *will almost always mean* my *home*
  >   I took her home. ... *whose home? Probably* hers, *but*
  >   She didn't have a place to stay, so I took her home. ... *means* my *home*

Comment: Great answer (+1), but I don't quite agree that "I brought her home" *usually* means the speaker's home. I think it could go either way. "You don't have a ride? I'll take you home," would be a transportation offer, not a pick-up line. And the next day: "It was too cold to walk last night – how did Martha get home?" In that case, I would answer, "I took her home," meaning, "I drove her to her house and dropped her off," not, "I took her to my place." But this isn't so much a criticism of your answer as it is an affirmation that – as you said – it gets _tricky_. There's inherent ambiguity here.

Comment: @J.R. My 'primary' second language is German, and that tends to colour my view of English. In German, *bringen* would be used in either case, so the marked contrast in English is something I very likely exaggerate.