# When should I use "to" before "home"

Tags: prepositions, american-english, adverbial-phrases

I have read that we do not use *to* before *home* as *home* is an adverb here:

> I am going **home**.
>
> You come **home**.
>
> He goes **home**.

We can use *to* before *home* in some cases:

> I am going **to his home**.
>
> You are coming **to my home**.
>
> He has been going **to your home**.

I have asked this question because I was reading about the direct and indirect speech and I found this piece of content on a website, so I got confused and landed here:

> There two ways to convey a message of a person, or the words spoken by
>   a person to other person.
>
> 1. Direct speech
> 2. Indirect speech
>
> Suppose your friend whose name is John tells you in school, “I will
>   give you a pen”. **You come to home** and you want to tell your brother
>   what your friend told you. There are two ways to tell him.

Comment: That is likely a typo in the website - that's not grammatical. You're correct about using _to_ only if there's a determiner before _home_ (_home_ is restricted in the determiners it can take, but that's a bit different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of not using "to" before "home" as it is an adverb is correct, as well as your second statement.  That use of "You come to home" is really, really strange and I've never heard that before. It seems to be a typo.  I would say "You come home and you want to tell your brother what your friend told you."  Either that or "You come to your home...", though the first one is much more natural.

Anyways, to answer your question, here are a couple of SE posts!

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/why-is-to-not-used-before-home

This one details how the word "home" functions in several ways (how it can be either a noun or an adverb).

[Can we use "to" before home, if we are using determiners (her, my, your etc.) before home?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17537/can-we-use-to-before-home-if-we-are-using-determiners-her-my-your-etc-be)

The second explanation is very, very good.  It details how "home" acts when bare and surrounded by other things.

I hope this helps, and feel free to ask if you have any more questions or if I didn't answer properly!  :)

I'm a native English speaker, from the Midwest (US), if that counts for anything.  There are variances in language, so if this is a regional thing, I don't know about it and I apologize for that.