# Why has "to" been omitted in "We walk home everyday"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm studying an English book instruction (Elementary 2). In a grammar part I've a sentence like this:

> 1. We walk home everyday.

but my knowledge says it's wrong and it has omitted "*to*" **before** "*home*" and the right form of this sentence should look like this:

> 2. We walk **to** home everyday.

Which one is true? It would be great if you explain WHY?

Comment: Related question https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24635/9161

Answer (score 5):

This is a peculiarity of the word "home".  It can be understood if you consider "home" to be used as an *adverb*, meaning "to home".

This allows  "Go home", "run home" and "walk home".  It also means that "Home we go" and "hammer the nail makes sense.

So while "Home" is normally a noun, but with verbs expressing motion, it can also be an adverb.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a peculiarity of "home": the preposition is always omitted when it's the object of *to* and may be omitted when it's the object of *at*. In both cases the possessive determiner is omitted.

> We walk <s>to our</s> home every day.
>   I'm [at <s>my</s>] home now.

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language classifies these as "prepositions"; I'm inclined to classify them (following CGEL's own practice in other contexts) as "fused-head preposition phrases".

Answer (score 1):

> We don't place a preposition "to" before the *adverb of place* **home**.

Briefly speaking, "home" in this case is an adverb of place which speaks about where the action took place, takes place or will take place. It also shows direction, in which case you can render it as if it were "homeward".