# Do you want to go (to the) father? (preposition + article addition)

Tags: prepositions

In case that a mother asks her son if he wants to go to his father.  What would be the natural way to ask him about that?

> "Do you want to go **to the** father?"

Or

> "Do you want to go father?"  (Without preposition and article,  the same like "Do you want to go home?"

To my ears the first choice sounds weird a little bit even I'm pretty sure it's grammatically correct.

Comment: What do you *mean* by "go to [your] father"? Some Victorians might have dispensed with any determiner, but almost no-one would use ***the*** - especially when talking to a child, and even *more* especially if it's that child's *own* father. The only natural context where I can imagine a native speaker saying the exact words in your first example would be a lawyer in a courtroom deciding on child custody in a messy divorce. But even he probably wouldn't say that to a six-year-old.

Comment: @Conceivableassessment *Home* is a bit exceptional because it can be a prepositional phrase on its own. See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/17543/3395) for some examples of its usage.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping the preposition *to* (not the infinitive marker *to* before *go*) leaves the reader/hearer no clue as to what role *father* plays in the sentence. In fact, it looks like *father* is a verb (as in "Do you want to go play?"), and the mother is asking her son if he wants to beget a child, which is very unlikely!

Beyond that, we would not say *the* father, unless somebody else's father has been mentioned in the conversation and contrasted with another relative; we would say *your* father to specify which father we had in mind.

> Do you want to go **to your** father?

Note that this construction is exactly how you yourself set the question up in the third person: "a mother asks her son if he wants to go **to his** father."