# to home/home question

Tags: grammar

First of all, I know "going to home" is grammatically incorrect, but what about this sentence: " I'm on a plane to home" meaning I'm currently on a plane and heading home. If I not use "to" that sentence looks just bad, maybe because there is no verb in it?

Comment: Related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/17537/9161

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the sentence would look bad without "to." It looks better to me without it. There is a verb, it's "am" inside the contraction "I'm".

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of workarounds for that. A couple common ones:

- I'm on a flight home
- I'm flying home
- I'm on a plane home

Note that "home" functions differently from other places. "Home" doesn't use "to" in this case. One can be "on the bus home", but one can't be "on the bus doctor's office". There is in fact a verb in both of your example sentences, "to be", hidden within "I'm" (I *am*).