# Please asking about "walking my bike" phrase

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction, usage

Could we use the phrase " I walked my bike to home. Or I walked my bike into home. Or I pressed my bike to home. or I pushed my bike to home."? Are they correct? Which one is natural sounding?
To home? Into home? Only home?
Please answer to me.

Comment: If you walked beside your bike and guided it with your hand (instead of riding it), you walked (or pushed) your bike home. Just home, no 'to' or 'into'.

Comment: [for your mental or written dictionary: go home, get home, leave home, arrive home, etc. ]

Answer (score 4):

The most idiomatic way to say this in American English is: *I walked my bike home*.

We use the phrase *walk my bike* to describe the action of walking while pushing or guiding a bicycle, typically by holding the handlebars with two hands, or the stem with one hand, or sometimes holding the seat (this is less common, because it's more difficult to steer).

Bicycles will typically roll easily on their own, meaning you don't have use much force to make them move forward.  Thus, there's an analogy to *walking my dog* (you don't have to work to make your dog walk, though you may need to guide it).

I suppose this is why *push my bike* is less common.  To me, at least, *pushing* implies more effort than *walking*.  I might use *push my bike* to describe moving a motorcycle (but this may not be correct - motorcycle riders have their own lingo).

---

There's a separate question here about *home/to home/into home*.  This question has been discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/why-is-to-not-used-before-home), [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17537/can-we-use-to-before-home-if-we-are-using-determiners-her-my-your-etc-be), [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229371/to-home-home-question), etc

Comment: If someone said, "I walked my bike home", I would understand that to mean, "to my property". Perhaps putting it in the garage or leaving it lying on the grass. But I'd generally assume they meant leaving it outside, because bikes are normally kept outside. If someone said, "I walked my bike into my home", I'd take that to mean that they took the bike into the house.

Comment: We generally contrast "walking a bike" with "riding a bike". If you ride a bike, you are sitting on the seat and your feet don't normally touch the ground. If you walk a bike, you are walking beside it while you hold onto it. I generally think of "push" as meaning to get behind something and press against it to move it forward, in contrast to "pull". So if someone said he "pushed his bike home" I'd picture him standing behind it pushing. If someone moved an object without being behind or  in front, like he was holding it beside him as he moved, I wouldn't call that either "pushing" or ...

Comment: ... "pulling" but would search for another word. Maybe "dragged" or "rolled", depending.